# How do I efficiently fill/remove in the chevron in this picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

[image]

How do I fill in the chevron in this picture to make a complete image? I'm planning to use the stars in my background, and the orbit for visual effects.

Comment: Our site is not intended for basic instruction of software tools. Please show us what you have tried or searched for so far and explain why that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the clone tool in photoshop, and you could stay disciplined when using it within a gradient.

HOWEVER, what i would do... is live trace the entire thing in illustrator as a flat, one color image, then i would cut out all of the white and keep the white as it's own layer, then id redraw the blue circle, fill it with an identical radial gradient, and then go back to your white stuff, delete the chevron paths, and with a little finesse, you will basically have recreated the thing as a vector (infinitely scaleable) piece of art. Hope this made sense.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of steps i'd have to go through to get there? I'm kind of a newbie; only had 1 month or so of practice.